# Jetson TX2 tensorflow per_process_gpu_memory_fraction variable cannot set to 1.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson

When I set per_process_gpu_memory from 0.5 to 1.0, there is not enough memory and it will crashed.

1) So, any ideas or suggestions to make it work?

2) Does convert tensorflow code to tensorRT will improve the performance (not for training, only for prediction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't set memory usage to 1.0. Remember, the TX2 is a SoC and the CPU cores and GPU all share a common pool of memory. If the GPU is using 100% of that memory, there is no memory left for the CPU and if I recall correctly, the default OS is not setup for any swap space.
2. There are a few benchmarks that show improvement when using TensorRT over just doing inference in TensorFlow. In theory, TensorRT is more optimized for inference on the GPU and runs a special set of kernels that it selects when building the engine. See here for a few benchmarks: https://github.com/NVIDIA-Jetson/tf_to_trt_image_classification